# Times Ten user privs

Tags: oracle, timesten

We have a times ten instance created by another user on a windows server 2008 r2 standard. I've created a dsn but when I try to connect it gives me a

```
7001:User authentication failed
```

On investigating some more, I understand that as the instance admin is different I don't have privs. But what do I need to do to get privs to connect and make changes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was to create a new internal user with admin rights to the cache db and it started working fine.